# C# and weather API, fetch specific data

Tags: c#

I am getting data from weather API and I would like to return only specific data lets say humidity not the whole object.

```
public Object getWeatherForcast()
    {
        string url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Aalborg&APPID=appid&units=imerial";

        var client = new WebClient();
        var content = client.DownloadString(url);
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var jsonContent = serializer.Deserialize<Object>(content);

        //here if I use only jsonContent it returns all data, unfortunately I don t know how to get
        //the specific data
        return jsonContent.main.humidity;


    }
```

here if I use only jsonContent it returns all data, unfortunately I don t know how to get
        the specific data

[image]

[image]

Comment: Before returning it you could use something like LINQ and select only the humidity. Quick and dirty trick, I'm sure other answers will be better.

Comment: Could you also post the JSON string you get from the API?

Comment: @Mahdi This is what you needed ? I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deserializing to a type `Object`, it would be recommended that you deserialize to your own type of object, like Weather report or something like that, so you can do something like this:

```
WeatherReport report = serializer.Deserialize<WeatherReport>(content);
```

That would be much easy for you.

Anyway, given what you have right there, you can do something like this:

```
jsonContent.main[2].ToString(); //Or whatever other method or property you prefer
```

Comment: The same problem, Object does not contain a definition for "main"...
"ToString()" does not seems to help...

Comment: try jsonContent[3][2].ToString();

Comment: `var client = new WebClient();
            var content = client.DownloadString(url);
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var jsonContent = serializer.Deserialize<Object>(content);
            return jsonContent[3][2].ToString();`

Should the code you suggested looks like this ? Message is "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an dexpression of type "object"

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to prepare a class(es) representing the data you want to read from the JSON, as already mentioned, but if you want to keep it your way, or just read single value (e.g. humidity from "main" section), you may use `dynamic` with the following small code snippet:

```
var jsonContent = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(content);
var humidity = jsonContent["main"]["humidity"];
```

EDIT

In your case `JavaScriptSerializer` deserializes objects to `Dictionary<string, object>`, so you have to access it's properties with indexer, as showed above. If you use `Newtonsoft.Json` library to deserialize JSON, using `dynamic` as well, you could get something like the following, cleaner sample, accessing the data using properties:

```
var jsonContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);
humidity = jsonContent.main.humidity;
```